# Upper bound for $|\mathbb E[f(X)] - f(0)|$ when $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is piecewise-linear with $\|f'\|_\infty \le 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian-integral, concentration-of-measure

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a piecewise linear function such that $f(0)=0$ and $\|f'\|_\infty \le 1$ and let $X$ be a Guassian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. What is an upper-bound for $|\mathbb E[f(X)]|$ ?

### Example

If $f(x) = \max(x,0)$, then $\mathbb E[f(X)]=\sigma/\sqrt{2\pi} = \mathcal O(\sigma)$.

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be more constraints for it to have a bound independent of $f$.

Consider: $f(x) = a - x$ for some large constant $a$. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = O(a)$ (e.g., when $a >> \sigma$).

**Edit:** With the new constraint, doubling the bound in the example (given in the question) gives a bound.

Comment: Sure enough I forgot the mention $f(0) = 0$. My bad. See update. (Also, I guess you meant to say $E[f(X)] = a \ne \mathcal O(\sigma)$ when $a \gg \sigma$)

Comment: Then just double what you put down in your example.

Comment: @dohmatob Then just double the bound you get in your example.

Comment: Actually, using MVT and Cauchy-Schwarz, one can show (see below) $|\mathbb E[f(X)]| \le \sigma $ if  $f$ is continuously differentiable with $\|f'\|_\infty \le 1$. Perhaps that's what you had in mind...

Comment: @dohmatob No that's not what I had in mind. Just double the bound put down in the example. Actually, y = |x| achieves the bound. Otherwise there is a point with (sub-)gradient bigger than 1. You can show this by contradiction. The bound derived this way is $\frac{2 \sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, which is tighter than $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one can get a bound for general $f \in \mathcal C^1$ for which $\|f'\|_\infty \le 1$, via the *Mean-Value Theorem* and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for expectations.

---

Indeed, the MVT gives $f(X) = \pm Xf'(\theta(X))$ for some $\theta(X)$ between $\min(X,0)$ and $\max(X,0)$. Here $\theta(X)$ is a random variable which depends measurably on $X$. Thus
$$
|\mathbb E[f(X)]| \overset{\text{MVT}}{=} |\mathbb E[Xf'(\theta(X))]| \overset{\text{C.S}}{\le} \sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2]}\sqrt{\mathbb E[(f'(\theta(X)))^2]} \le \sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2]} = \sigma.
$$